# Updating overflow without removing elements from the div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I used:

```
parentNode.removeChild( divHere );
```

It does work and the scroll bar for the overflow updates accordingly. If I use JS to 'divHere.style.visibily = "hidden";' well that doesn't work anymore. What I've done pretty much is create 115 divs that are in a container div and the user can select filters to show only the images they want, all the divs have a background image and are essentially just an image with a name under it.

So I have 2 questions:

1) Is there a way to update the overflow and make it not take hidden elements into consideration?

2) If 1) isn't possible than when I use removeChild to remove a div from the container, it does indeed disappear but what exactly happens to it? Does it disappear off the page because it's not added to any element on the page? So it essentially works like it's hidden? I don't have to worry about people seeing the images in some completely weird spot in some lesser used browser?

and well 3) If you have a better method of doing this it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: why not just use `display:none` in stead of `visibility:hidden`?

Comment: Wow awesome answer. Thank you for finding an even better/easier solution. Question now is, when I want to put them back what do I set the display too? What's the default? Thank you so much for your answer =)

Comment: the default for a div is block, so just put them back to `display:block`to make them show up again. Should work fine in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering guys, and thanks Peter for the simple solution. I do have one more question though. I was reading about Reflow and how it's the main problem for slow DOM scripts. Since changing the display or visibility accesses the style and causes the reflow, do you know if just removing them from the div and then re-adding them later on would be a better solution? Even if there'd be more coding involved would it not cause reflow's and give greater performance? Any idea? http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=3#reflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `removeChild()` method removes a specified child node of the specified element and returns the removed node as a Node object, or null if the node does not exist.
That null means that the element is now removed from your mark-up.

You should use it to not let the browser take that into consideration, as the browser will not find that element in the mark-up.

You can do it in this way as well:

```
$(document).remove(object_to_remove);
```

FInd more about it: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Unfortunately I prefer not to use jQuery, but your explanation still stands. I knew what the syntax did for the most part, was just worried about it appearing in some random place if it didn't have a parent. +1 for taking the time to answer

Comment: btw why not jQuery? are you not allowed?

Comment: No that's not the case, it's my own project. I just don't see the purpose of using a library when the native code is just as simple to use. Maybe for more complicated things jQuery is worth it, but for small tasks like this I don't see the point

Comment: oh! so my answer is not what you wanted?

Comment: @HateNames I would not exactly call working with 115 divs a small task. 15, maybe, but not 115. How are you adding them to your page? Manually, or do you have a script that iterates over something and adds the divs to the page's DOM?

Comment: I'd agree JAB but I'm not really doing complicated things to the 115 divs. I'm only changing their location and hiding the ones according to a filter. I initially used insertBefore to reposition the divs but I couldnt for the life of me find a way to use transitions with insertBefore so I switched to just changing the style.left and style.top css properties. Would you have a better suggestion, besides the datatables which I will already look into

Comment: @JAB I'm currently using a for loop to create and give all the properties to all 115 divs. But I was debating of writing it all in html since I read it helps initial load times, thoughts?

Comment: @HateNames I think that might increase load time of the page itself, actually. It would be nicer to the users to have the page load with a placeholder of sorts, and then have the Javascript add the elements to the page. And if you add the elements hidden/undisplayed first, you could put in some CSS to animate the transition to displayed so that the elements look nice as they appear.

Comment: So you're saying writing it all in html would increase the page load time? These divs arent actually showing up at the start, the user has to click on a menu item for them to show up, so you'd suggest I load the image first and then do something like, setTimeout 10ms to add the elements after the user has loaded the page? Right now I do have css to animate the divs but it only works if I change the left and top styles, compared to if I used insertBefore to sort the divs

Comment: @HateNames That's even more of a reason to do delayed loading, if the elements aren't even showing up to start with. You do want to be careful that you don't cause the page to become temporarily unresponsive while the divs are generated, though, if it takes a user-noticeable amount of time to generate them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I may have a response for the third part of your question. That large number of divs in your containing div and the usage of filtering make me think you might want to look into using the DataTables plugin for jQuery (http://www.datatables.net/). It has some very nice features for sorting/filtering/etc. a large number of data elements and supports a variety of data sources. There are also some plugins for the plugin if the basic functionality isn't enough for you.

There is a bit of a learning curve if you want to do more complex stuff with it, and it might be tricky to get used to if you haven't worked with jQuery much (though being someone who hasn't worked with jQuery all that much due to not doing much web development, I can say that I quite like using it whenever I get the chance, although that may just be due to me enjoying learning how to do new things in programming), but I feel that if you're willing to spend the time on it you will have something much more maintainable than what you currently have.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this. I will definitely look into it since later on I might have 300-400 items to filter through, so definitely something that might interest me. Thanks for the info